# How Do I Get An Explicit List From svn:mergeinfo To Compare Across Branches

Tags: svn, merge

I want to compare the svn:mergeinfo between 2 long lived branches.

If I do `svn propget svn:mergeinfo` I get something like this:

```
trunk:5085-5089,5092-5095,5102
```

The use of the ranges makes it difficult to compare.
How can I make it list everything instead? e.g.

```
 trunk:5085,5086,5087,5088,5089,5092,5093,5094,5095,5102
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the mergeinfo command like so:

```
svn mergeinfo mergeinfo --show-revs merged $SRC $TARGET
```

Where `$SRC` is the branch the merges are coming from and `$TARGET` is the branch they're going to.

Do that for each of your 2 `$TARGET` branches to get the changes that were merged from the `$SRC` branch and then compare the output.

If you have multiple `$SRC` branches you'll need to repeat all of the above for each one.